# llvm "replaceinstwithvalue" does not work

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction, llvm

I am a llvm newbie.

I am trying to write a llvm pass to optimize for algebraic identities in a function (like, if my function has an instruction a = b * 0, my pass should replace all following uses of "a" with 0).

So, my pass looks like follows:-

```
...

for (Function::iterator f_it = F.begin(), f_ite = F.end(); f_it != f_ite; ++f_it) {
  for(BasicBlock::iterator b_it = f_it->begin(), b_ite = f_it->end(); b_it != b_ite; ++b_it) {
    if(op->getOpcode() == Instruction::Mul) {
      if(ConstantInt *CI_F = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(&*b_it->getOperand(0))) {
        if(CI_F->isZero()) {
          firstop_zero = 1;
        }
      }
      if(ConstantInt *CI_S = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(&*b_it->getOperand(1))) {
        if(CI_S->isZero()) {
          secop_zero = 1;
        }
      }
      if(first_zero || second_zero) {   
        errs()<<"found zero operand\n";  
        ReplaceInstWithValue(b_it->getParent()->getInstList(),b_it,(first_zero?(&*b_it->getOperand(1)):(&*b_it->getOperand(0))));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can see that my comment "found zero operand gets printed out on std-err, but I can't see the replacement in the resulting .bc's disassembly.

What am I missing here? Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks a lot!
Praveena

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (Function::iterator f_it = F.begin(), f_ite = F.end(); f_it != f_ite; ++f_it) {
for(BasicBlock::iterator b_it = f_it->begin(), b_ite = f_it->end(); b_it != b_ite; ++b_it) {
 Instruction *I = *b_it;
 Value *Zeroval;
if(op->getOpcode() == Instruction::Mul) {
  if(ConstantInt *CI_F = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(&*b_it->getOperand(0))) {
    if(CI_F->isZero()) {
      firstop_zero = 1;
      Zeroval = CI_F;
    }
  }
  if(ConstantInt *CI_S = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(&*b_it->getOperand(1))) {
    if(CI_S->isZero()) {
      secop_zero = 1;
      ZeroVal = CI_S;
    }
  }
  if(first_zero || second_zero) {   
    errs()<<"found zero operand\n";  
    I->ReplaceAlluseswith(ZeroVal);
  }
}
 }
```

}